# "Caps Lock is on"-tooltip doesn't go away (Citrix? Codejock?)

Tags: windows, mfc, tooltip, citrix, capslock

I'm working with an MFC application. In some of our forms, we have password fields - ordinary `CEdit` controls with the `ES_PASSWORD` style set. When focus is moved to a password field, Windows displays a tooltip-warning if the user has Caps Lock on. (See [screendump here](http://www.agodata.se/bilder/CapsLockIsOn.png)) Which is OK - the password is case sensitive, so it's good that the user gets informed he should turn Caps Lock off.

But sometimes the warning doesn't go away. Even after the `CEdit` control (and the whole view window) has been deleted/destroyed. The "tooltip balloon" remains on screen, on top of everything else. (Hides new controls.) The only way to get rid of it is to close the application and restart it.

The problem doesn't appear so often, but is very annoying for the user when it does. As far as we know, this has only happend to users running our application under Citrix - not on a standalone PC. Our application is using Codejock's XTP, but the tooltip is localized so it seems to be generated by Windows.

(1) Does anybody know what can caus e this? We haven't been able to find anything about it online! Could it be a Citrix problem? Or are we wrong about this beeing a Windows thing - could this be a Codejock bug?

(2) Is there a way to fix this? (`CEdit::HideBalloonTip`/`EM_HIDEBALLOONTIP` does not help.)

(3) If there isn't a solution to the problem, can we disable the "Caps Lock is on"-tooltip completely for the `CEdit` control? Better not to show the tooltip at all, than having this problem.

Comment: If you can recreate the problem, you might want to try using Spy++ to get the characteristics of the tool tip window.  This may help you to determine if the window is still displayed (from within your code) and provide the ability to dismiss it.

Comment: In `CEdit`'s parent window, override `OnLButtonDown` and call `CEdit::HideBalloonTip` or `SetFocus()`, see if tool-tip closes when user clicks in the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the Balloon tip you can filter the `EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` message as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081010-00/?p=20603):

```
WNDPROC g_wpEdit;

LRESULT CALLBACK NoBalloonWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg,
                                  WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (uMsg) {
  case EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP: return FALSE;
  }
  return CallWindowProc(g_wpEdit, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL
OnCreate(HWND hwnd, LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)
{
    g_hwndChild = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), NULL,
            ES_PASSWORD | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0,
            0, 0, hwnd, NULL, g_hinst, 0);
    if (!g_hwndChild) return FALSE;

    g_wpEdit = SubclassWindow(g_hwndChild, NoBalloonWndProc);

    return TRUE;
}
```